# Why can't I open another process in Qt framework with this function?

Tags: c++, qt, exe, qprocess

In the Qt framework we're supposed to be able to open another .exe using QProcess. The following doesn't work when I click a button and the callback is called:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
    QString wordPath = "C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe";

    process->start(wordPath);
}
```

However if I change process->start(wordPath) to:

```
process->start(wordPath, QStringList());
```

Which is an overload of the same function, it works. The second parameter is supposed to be the arguments passed to the new process you want to start. The only way I can make the single-argument version work it seems is if something is in my PATH variable, because both "explorer.exe" and "msconfig" work. What is the story behind this only working with the second QStringList(), which is just an empty list?

In another SO question I saw a user specifically add an empty string, like this:

```
QString wordPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\WINWORD.EXE"
process->start(wordPath, QStringList() << "");
```

I would love to know what the reason is behind this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your path "C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe" contains spaces, so when you use the first version the program is interpreted as being "C:/Program" with arguments "Files/Internet" and "Explorer/iexplore.exe".
The second version treats all of the first argument as the program and the QStringList as the arguments.

Comment: Thank you. So even though there's a specific overloaded function to take extra arguments, the single parameter one will consider anything after spaces parameter arguments to the new process you start?

Comment: Yes. It takes a full command line, not the name of the executable. See the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start-1). They even specifically advise against this function, and provide a preprocessor macro to forbid its use entirely.

Answer (score 1):

From the Qt documentation:

Arguments containing spaces must be quoted to be correctly supplied to the new process.

Try
`QString wordPath = "\"C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe\"";`